# Word, VSTO, OpenXml - Inserting XML into Paragraph object

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am using the following code to inject xml (openxml) into the range of a paragraph in Word. The problem is I get an error message stating "XML markup cannot be inserted into the specified location"

c# code:

```
try
{    
    string oxml = ""; // this contains the xml listed below
    // get the first paragraph
    Paragraph p = this.Paragraphs[1];
    object missing = Type.Missing;
    // insert openxml formatted xml into paragraph range
    p.Range.InsertXML(oxml, ref missing);  // causes the exception  
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //_logger.Error("OpenXml Injection", ex);
}
```

XML that is to be injected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<?mso-application progid="Word.Document"?>
<pkg:package xmlns:pkg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/xmlPackage" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
  <w:document xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" mc:Ignorable="w14 wp14">
    <w:p>
      <w:r>
        <w:t xml:space="preserve">(a) Costs and Expenses</w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:del w:id="33350" w:author="Exemplify">
        <w:r>
          <w:delText xml:space="preserve">. </w:delText>
        </w:r>
      </w:del>
      <w:r>
        <w:t xml:space="preserve"> The</w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:commentRangeStart w:id="33351" />
      <w:del w:id="33352" w:author="Exemplify">
        <w:r>
          <w:delText xml:space="preserve"> Borrower</w:delText>
        </w:r>
      </w:del>
      <w:commentRangeEnd w:id="33351" />
      <w:r>
        <w:commentReference w:id="33351" />
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:t xml:space="preserve"> shall pay (i) all reasonable out-of-pocket expenses incurred by the Administrative Agent and its Affiliates</w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:del w:id="33353" w:author="Exemplify">
        <w:r>
          <w:delText xml:space="preserve">, </w:delText>
        </w:r>
      </w:del>
      <w:ins w:id="33354" w:author="Exemplify">
        <w:r>
          <w:t xml:space="preserve"> (</w:t>
        </w:r>
      </w:ins>
      <w:r>
        <w:t xml:space="preserve">.</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
  </w:document>
</pkg:package>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To use InsertXML, the XML either has to be a complete, valid Word 2003 WordProcessingML document, or a complete, valid Open Office XML document in flat OPC format. At the moment the XML you have isn't either of those.

To be a valid Flat OPC package, the package has to contain Parts, and to define the necessary relationship parts.

To be a valid Word 2003 XML document, the namespace declaration needs to be different, the document element needs to be

```
<w:wordDocument>
```

and inside that you need a

```
<w:body>
```

element. I suspect some of the elements you have are not valid for that XML vocabulary (you can check yourself) but for example the following XML with some elements and attributes removed should inject OK:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<?mso-application progid="Word.Document"?>
<w:wordDocument xmlns:w="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml">
  <w:body>
    <w:p>
      <w:r>
        <w:t>(a) Costs and Expenses</w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:t> The</w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:t> shall pay (i) all reasonable out-of-pocket expenses incurred by the Administrative Agent and its Affiliates</w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:t>.</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
  </w:body>
</w:wordDocument>
```

For the Word 2007 and later XML, everything needs to be inside a part within the package, and the package has to define some relationships. In this case, the following would do (you only need the namespace defintions that are actually referenced in your XML):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<?mso-application progid="Word.Document"?>
<pkg:package xmlns:pkg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/xmlPackage">
  <pkg:part pkg:name="/_rels/.rels" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml">
    <pkg:xmlData>
      <Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">
        <Relationship Id = "rId1" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument" Target="word/document.xml" />
      </Relationships>
    </pkg:xmlData>
  </pkg:part>
  <pkg:part pkg:name="/word/document.xml" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml">
    <pkg:xmlData>
      <w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
        <w:body>
          <w:p>
            <w:r>
              <w:t>(a) Costs and Expenses</w:t>
            </w:r>
            <w:del w:id="33350" w:author="Exemplify">
              <w:r>
                <w:delText>. </w:delText>
              </w:r>
            </w:del>
            <w:r>
              <w:t> The</w:t>
            </w:r>
            <w:commentRangeStart w:id="33351" />
            <w:del w:id="33352" w:author="Exemplify">
              <w:r>
                <w:delText> Borrower</w:delText>
              </w:r>
            </w:del>
            <w:commentRangeEnd w:id="33351" />
            <w:r>
              <w:t> shall pay (i) all reasonable out-of-pocket expenses incurred by the Administrative Agent and its Affiliates</w:t>
            </w:r>
            <w:del w:id="33353" w:author="Exemplify">
              <w:r>
                <w:delText>, </w:delText>
              </w:r>
            </w:del>
            <w:ins w:id="33354" w:author="Exemplify">
              <w:r>
                <w:t> (</w:t>
              </w:r>
            </w:ins>
            <w:r>
              <w:t>.</w:t>
            </w:r>
          </w:p>
        </w:body>
      </w:document>
    </pkg:xmlData>
  </pkg:part>
</pkg:package>
```

I have omitted the xml:space="preserve" attributes - you may need them. I have also omitted the following chunk

```
            <w:r>
              <w:commentReference w:id="33351" />
            </w:r>
```

which will cause failure. I would guess it's because it actually references a comment with an Id that doesn't exist.